# disable a function from loading when page loads

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, load

I have some php, javascript and html code.  I have a few lines that are identical in 2 functions.  When the page loads I just want one of those functions to basically execute and not the other, how can I prevent the other from executing?  Example below:

```
Function 1()
document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows

Function 2()
document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows
```

I don't want the 2nd function to run, right now in the first function there is some code that occurs, so function 2 is actually overwriting function 1's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is some sort of a flag. For example:

```
var wasExecuted;

function runOnce(){
   if( wasExecuted ){
      return;
   }else{
      wasExecuted = true;
      document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows;
   }
}

runOnce(); //this will run through the 'else' 
runOnce(); //this will exit the runOnce function (as the flag has been set to true)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I actually was using a flag for some other onchange functions and should've used it for this also.  It is working thanks to everyone for their input.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you aren't capturing your functions in brackets? Try the below code.

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows
};

function 2(){
document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows
}
```

Comment: actually I am capturing the code in brackets, forgot to post it up (the code you see on here is just an example).  Is there another way to put it where you can say don't load or run function 2?  I don't really want to say onload, although I did try it and didn't work.

Comment: that's what I thought too, it's not running it perse but is assigning values to the variables?

Answer (score 0):

What about a flag value?
like:

```
var myFlag = false;
function 1(){
 if(!myFlag){
  document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows;
  myFlag = true;
 }
}

function 2(){
 if(!myFlag){
  document.getElementById('field1').length=$field1_numrows;
  myFlag = true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more generic solution here :

```
var already_executed = (function () {
    var done = {};
    return function (tag) {
        var res = done[tag];
        done[tag] = true;
        return res;
        }
    })();
```

A tag identifies a group of functions. Only the first of the group will be executed.

You can reuse the same mechanism with different groups of functions by assigning them different tags.

For instance :

```
function a() {
    if (already_executed("a_or_b")) return;
    console.log ("a is executing");
    // rest of the code
}

function b() {
    if (already_executed("a_or_b")) return;
    console.log ("b is executing");
    // rest of the code
}

function c() {
    if (already_executed("c_or_d")) return;
    console.log ("c is executing");
    // rest of the code
}

function d() {
    if (already_executed("c_or_d")) return;
    console.log ("d is executing");
    // rest of the code
}
```

Calling

```
a();
b();
c();
d();
```

Will result in

```
a is executing
c is executing
```

All this being said, I think refactoring your code would be a better investment than relying on such hacks. Keeping wrong code dormant behind such a mechanism is asking for trouble, in my opinion.